# How can we pass requests from one page to another in electron

Tags: electron

How can we pass requests from one page to another in electron, like do we do in html or php.

For Eg: In html or php, we can pass them like test.html?name=jaydev

I want this in my electron app.

For example, i am loading index page in the main window using

```
mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html');
```

Then i load machines.html in the same main window using

```
mainWindow.loadURL('file://' + __dirname + '/machines.html');
```

Now how can i pass some requests from index.html to machines.html?

Can any suggest a solution for this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: i dont have an idea how to do that. Can you help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use that convention for passing values to an `iFrame` loading within `Electron` – I don't know if it will work in your case, The script below is called when the page has loaded. It gets params which were passed to the `src` of the `iFrame`:

```
video.html?videoSrc=clark-8.mp4&poster=clark-8.png
```

I don't know what you are trying to do or what data you are trying to pass between webcontent – but it seems like there are a variety of ways to go about it.

1. Pass the data back to the main process and have the new webcontent request it - or push it to the new webcontent once it has loaded.
2. Use [cookies and local storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-cookies)

---

```
<script>
    function getParamValue(paramName) {
        var url = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var qArray = url.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < qArray.length; i++) {
            var pArr = qArray[i].split('=');
            if (pArr[0] == paramName)
                return pArr[1];
        }
    }

    // grap the video & poster frame refs from url
    var videoSrc = getParamValue('videoSrc');
    videoSrc = "assets/videos/" + videoSrc;

    var poster = getParamValue('poster');
    poster = "assets/images/" + poster;

    videojs("videoPlayer", {}, function () {
        this.src(videoSrc);
        this.poster(poster);
        this.load();
    });

</script>
```

Comment: That's works for me. You are awesome. Thanks for solving my issue. Sorry for the late reply